# searching for a particular character, except in comments of a file

Tags: python, regex, string

I am working on python migration from 2 to 3.
I want to check if the files have a "/" operation. Since the files are too many, I plan to use a script to do so.
Although the script works fine, some files have comments and those comments have the "/" in between.

Eg:

```
File:
import sys
#blah blah
     #get/set       ---This gets detected
a=5
b=2
c=a/b  --- I want to detect this
d=5/3   --- I want to detect this
```

I do not want the comments section to be considered, is there any regex that could help me here?

Script:

```
text = '/'
APP_FOLDER: "C\Users\Files"
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(APP_FOLDER):
    for inputFile in filenames:
        if pathlib.Path(inputFile).suffix == ".py":
            file_path = os.path.join(dirpath, inputFile)
            with open(file_path) as f:
                num_lines = len(f.readlines())
                with open(file_path, 'r') as fp:
                    for line in fp:
                        if re.findall(text, line, flags=re.IGNORECASE):
                            file_count = file_count + 1
                            print "File path: " + file_path
                            print "File name: " + inputFile
                            print "*******************************************************************************"
                            break
```

Looking forward for suggestions. PS: The # symbol need not be the first character in the line.

Comment: Provide short input data. What / has before and after?

Comment: It seems quite possible to write a regex that finds all `/` chars that occur before the first `#` char in a line.  But there is also the possibility of `/` inside quoted strings, which should be ignored too - this is harder with regex, especially when you can have multi-line strings. What you really want is to scan the AST of your code files for division operations, rather than making a regex that half works. That is how the https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html migration tool works. Have a look at https://github.com/python-rope/rope/blob/master/docs/library.rst#quick-start

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:**
The comments on your question actually give a better answer than this...

You can do this quite easily by simply splitting on the `#` character and only evaluating the part before the `#` character. See below:

```py
def find_char_in_text(text, subtext, commentchar='#'):
    result = []
    for line in text.split('\n'):
        if commentchar in line:
            # split on the comment character
            # reason to not change line itself directly is
            # so you can add the whole line to the results.
            evaluate_this = line.split(commentchar)[0]
        else:
            evaluate_this = line
        if subtext in evaluate_this:
            result.append(line)
    return result


text = """File:
import sys
#blah blah
     #get/set       ---This gets detected
a=5
b=2
c=a/b  --- I want to detect this
d=5/3   --- I want to detect this"""


for result in find_char_in_text(text, '/'):
    print(result)
```

**output**

```
c=a/b  --- I want to detect this
d=5/3   --- I want to detect this
```